# How to run cron job every 90 days starting at specific date?

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins pipelineTrigger that I want to run every 90 days starting a particular day.

currently I have:

`pipelineTriggers([cron('0 1 01 */3 *')])`

However, I'd like it to start on a particular day, ie: Nov 20, 2022 and run every 90 days after that day.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Every 90 days or on the 20th of every third month? They are different. Or the third Sunday of every third month?

Comment: Id like for it to run every 90 days starting Nov 20. The reasoning is, if I set it to 90 days, it would start from todays date rather than on the 20th.